# Multiple responsive video.js players

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I'm using this solution, http://daverupert.com/2012/05/making-video-js-fluid-for-rwd/, to make the videojs player fluid.  My problem is when I have multiple videos (each with a unique id), I'm not sure how to make this work.

Here is my dev site I have 3 videos on, http://tweedee.e-mediaresources.info/

Here is the code I have for the player (from Dave Rupert's solution above):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Once the video is ready
    _V_('#my_video_1').ready(function(){

        var myPlayer = this;    // Store the video object
        var aspectRatio = 9/16; // Make up an aspect ratio

        function resizeVideoJS(){
            // Get the parent element's actual width
            var width = document.getElementById(myPlayer.id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
            // Set width to fill parent element, Set height
            myPlayer.width(width).height( width * aspectRatio );
        }

        resizeVideoJS(); // Initialize the function
        window.onresize = resizeVideoJS; // Call the function on resize
    });
    </script>
```

This code works fine for one video, but how do I do multiple ids???  As you can see in my dev site, I just replicated the script above three times (each with a different id) and that only causes the last video to be fluid.

Comment: Dev site no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

you overwrite window.onresize() each time, so only the last one is used.
replace

```
window.onresize = resizeVideoJS
```

with :

```
 window.addEventListener("resize", resizeVideoJS, false); // all browsers except IE before version 9
```

Comment: Yes...this does help with resizing all three players.  Any idea though how to consolidate the js though so it's not the same script replicated 3 times (it works, but it's ugly & not efficient)?

Answer (score 2):

The following works. It does involve a bit of repetition, which I think you might be able to avoid if you used something like jQuery's [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to wait until the `ready` event is fired for all of the video players, but it's a lot neater than duplicating the resize method as you're currently doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var players = ['my_video_1', 'my_video_2', 'my_video_3'];
    var aspectRatio = 9/16;

    // Catch each of the player's ready events and resize them individually
    // jQuery deferred might be a neater way to wait for ready on all components to load and avoid a bit of repetition
    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i ++) {
        _V_('#' + players[i]).ready(function() {
            resizeVideoJS(this);
        });
    }

    // Loop through all the players and resize them 
    function resizeVideos() {
        for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i ++) {
            var player = _V_('#' + players[i]);
            resizeVideoJS(player);
        }           
    }

    // Resize a single player
    function resizeVideoJS(player){
        // Get the parent element's actual width
        var width = document.getElementById(player.id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
        // Set width to fill parent element, Set height
        player.width(width).height( width * aspectRatio );
    }

    window.onresize = resizeVideos;

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// jQuery deferred might be a neater way to wait for ready 
// on all components to load and avoid a bit of repetition
for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i ++) {
    _V_('#' + players[i]).ready(function() {
        resizeVideoJS(this);
    });
}

// Loop through all the players and resize them 
function resizeVideos() {
    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i ++) {
        var player = _V_('#' + players[i]);
        resizeVideoJS(player);
    }           
}

// Resize a single player
function resizeVideoJS(player){
    // Get the parent element's actual width
    var width = document.getElementById(player.id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
    // Set width to fill parent element, Set height
    player.width(width).height( width * aspectRatio );
}

window.onresize = resizeVideos;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified net.uk.sweet's very helpful answer above into a working script which deals with multiple video players using video js - which are also responsive. You can find my article (which also shows an example) here = http://www.andy-howard.com/videojsmultipleresponsivevideos/index.html

This also includes a provided callback function if you require it.

Comment: The link gives a 404 now.

Answer (score -1):

you can use css rather than javascript :

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}  

.video-js {
    padding-top: 55.25%;
}

     <div class="wrapper">                                 
      <video id="video-player" width="auto" height="auto" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" data-setup="{}">                                         
       </video>                                 
     </div>
```

Comment: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/videodrome/videojs/barebones.php this link will help you