# play video when user scrolls specifically using video.js

Tags: javascript, video.js

I realise variants of this question have been asked before, but none specifically relating to how to do it on video.js

I'm using video.js for my videos. I need the videos to play when the user scrolls to their view. Many people have asked about html5 videos but I would like to know on video.js specifically. I've done the following but no luck -

```
var videos = videojs('movie-id_html5_api');
videojs("movie-id_html5_api").ready(function(){
  var videos = this;
  fraction = 0.8;
  function checkScroll() {

  for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

    var video = videos[i];

    var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
        b = y + h, //bottom
        visibleX, visibleY, visible;

        visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
        visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

        visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

        if (visible > fraction) {
            videos.play();

        } else {
            videos.pause();
        }

   }

  }

    });
    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
```

I should also mention I have multiple videos with the same ID 'movie-id_html5_api' and I would all like to get them to play when scrolled.

thank you in advance!!

Comment: Take a look at the videoJS docs: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/setup.md. Under Step 2: "The 'id' Attribute: Should be used and unique for every video on the same page."

Comment: Also, if you want them all to play at the same time, why not add a class to each video, then iterate over all them to play each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5pkr88y/1/) to only play each video if it is scrolled into view. If the video is not in view, it is paused. Credit to this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441757/multiple-responsive-video-js-players)  for the playVideos function and also for storing each video player id in an array. Also credit to this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling) for the isOnScreen() function.

```
videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.swf";
var players = ['example_video_1', 'example_video_2'];

window.addEventListener("resize", playVideos, false);
window.addEventListener("scroll", playVideos, false);

// Loop through all the players, check if video player is visible in the viewport. If it is visible, play it. If not, do not play it.
function playVideos() {

    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) 
    {
        var videoPlayer = $('#' + players[i]);
        var videoPlayerElem = _V_('#' + players[i]);

        if (isOnScreen(videoPlayer))
        {
             videoPlayerElem.play();
        }
        else
        {
             videoPlayerElem.pause();
        }     
    }

}

function isOnScreen(element) {
   var elementOffsetTop = element.offset().top;
   var elementHeight = element.height();

   var screenScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   var screenHeight = $(window).height();

   var scrollIsAboveElement = elementOffsetTop + elementHeight - screenScrollTop >= 0;
   var elementIsVisibleOnScreen = screenScrollTop + screenHeight - elementOffsetTop >= 0;

   return scrollIsAboveElement && elementIsVisibleOnScreen;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! is there any particular reason you've chosen to use the flash option? I wanted my videos to not have to depend on flash for ios compatibility..

Comment: also, I wish to play each video when the user scrolls down to see each individual one. much like this http://jsfiddle.net/jAsDJ/  - it seems in your answer both videos start as soon as the user scrolls. thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @user3658991 - I'm almost sure that including the swf file is standard use for VideoJS. If I'm correct, VideoJS uses flash as a fallback option if HTML5 capabilities are not present.